# Установить GitLab на сервер, на котором стоит ОС Ubuntu Server 13.10

Tags: gems, ruby, ubuntu

Добрый день, я уже несколько дней пытаюсь установить GitLab на сервер, на котором стоит ОС Ubuntu Server 13.10. Все делаю по официальной инструкции https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md, но когда я дошел до раздела **Install Init Script** начались проблемы, хотя до этого все шло отлично и без ошибок...

Выполняю команду **sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres aws**. Команда проходит удачно и пишет *Your bundle is complete! Gems in the groups development, test, postgres and aws were not installed*.

Но дальше начинаются проблемы, когда набираю команду **sudo cp lib/support/init.d/gitlab /etc/init.d/gitlab**. Получаю такой вывод: **cp: cannot stat '/lib/support/init.d/gitlab /etc/init.d/gitlab': No such file or directory**.

Дальше больше - ввожу команду **sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production** (Check if GitLab and its environment are configured correctly). Так вот вывод один раз показал, что у меня ОШИБКИ, потом ничего не делая ввожу еще раз эту же команду - ВСЕ ОК.

В общем я уже в шоке... Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: > один раз показал, что у меня ОШИБКИ

Нужны логи, но, возможно, скрипт сам все поправил при первом запуске

> cp: cannot stat '/lib/support/init.d/gitlab /etc/init.d/gitlab

содержимое этого файла можно найти здесь: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/lib/support/init.d/gitlab

потребуется немного танцев с бубном и wget или git clone плюс последующее копирование из файла. Через путти все должно быть вообще очень просто.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду зайти по ssh с помощью putty и залить файл на сервер?! Я правильно Вас понимаю?

Comment: Я имел в виду копипейстом, самое безопасное будет слить его через гит. Смысл в том, что тем или иным способом надо его с гитхаба стащить и поместить, куда было указано.

Comment: @eprivalov1, можете просто взять по ссылке текст (copy-paste) и положить его в /etc/init.d

Правда остается вопрос с правами, owner и группой, но думаю, что тсандартные 

     rwxr-xr-x root root 

подойдут

Comment: И последний вопрос какое расширение должно быть у файла gitlab? gitlab.sh??

Линукс меня просто убивает, только что ввел опять команду **sudo cp lib/support/init.d/gitlab /etc/init.d/gitlab**, но уже все прошло без ошибок... только файл не появился, сейчас буду пробовать через putty...

Comment: IMHO у Вас не прошла команда 

    cp lib/support/init.d/gitlab /etc/init.d/gitlab

значит, никакого расширения.

Comment: в юниксах расширения (на уровне системы) не имеют почти никакой роли, файл без расширения вообще - это обычное дело.

Comment: Да, так и есть, уже все ОК, спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Внимательно смотрите на команду и ошибку:

```
sudo cp lib/support/init.d/gitlab /etc/init.d/gitlab

cp: cannot stat '/lib/support/init.d/gitlab /etc/init.d/gitlab
```

обраттите внимание на лидирующий бэкслеш в ошибке, оно ищет это начиная от рута файловой системы. А мне чтото подсказывает что должно братся из установочной директории. Следовательно, при выполнение команды вы находились в коре файловой системы. Перейдите в установочную директорию и повторите команду, должно всё пройти удачно.